# How to synchronize Tables (Structure not Data) of two SQL Server databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two different databases of SQL Server, called `DB1` and `DB2`. I want to synchronize tables, views and stored procedures of these two databases. Let me clarify, I am not asking for a data sync - what I want is to only sync the structure of the two databases.

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: This seems like an odd request, but you could set up DDL triggers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: So what's the big deal? You make a change in one and you immediately do the same thing in the other. Do this with scripts and it is trivial to accomplish. If you use SSMS gui - well, don't. Do it with scripts. You will become a better, more effective, and more proficient developer.

Comment: Dear SMor, in this scenario, it hasn't happen. I just updated one db, now I want to update other one accordingly. Doing this with scripts one by one will take lot of time also need to search which table needs to be added and which is not.

Comment: Are both tables in the same database Or do you need to sync 2 databases (which is common task and have lot of tools for this) ?

Comment: There are tools - SSDT is one - that will compare schemas and generate a script to make them the same.

Comment: Dear Ronen Ariely, I need to sync two different databases.

Comment: OK, I see that my question to clarify your needs already led to one answer, which is using Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) `:-)` . This answer is not full yet since we still need more information. Anyhow, another option is to manually use simple transact SQL queries. If using the Built-in tool does not fit you, then please inform us and we can provide a manual solution. **Next question to clarify is**, Do you want this procedure to be automatically once you change the table in one database, or do is it OK to schedule the task of comparing?

Comment: @RonenAriely, Yes, I don't want this procedure to be **automatic** in the way you asked. It is manual in that way. But yes, I want different _DBs_ to automatically compare their tables and sync each other whenever I manually want it.

Comment: Then basically you got the answer from David Browne `;-)`. I hoped that I will have a chance to write some queries today, but in this case using the built in tools is probably best `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is called "Schema Compare", and there are several tools that can do this for you, including the free [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-2017), available for download [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017).

Views and stored procedures can simply be scripted from one database and applied to the other, but for tables you need to calculate the differences between the existing and new table and generate a script to apply the changes without loosing the data currently in the target tables.